# PHP convert "," to "."

Tags: php

My data (example)

`05.07.2000,00:00:00,0,6856868,0,7779905,0,6856868,0,6856868,42539730`

I want convert (example)

`05.07.2000,00:00:00,0.6856868,0.7779905,0.6856868,0.6856868,42539730`

, to .

i want convert third , character - fifth , character - seventh , character - ninth , character

Please str replace inadequate.

i use str replace

`05.07.2000.00:00:00.0.6856868.0.7779905.0.6856868.0.6856868.42539730`

i want

`05.07.2000,00:00:00,0.6856868,0.7779905,0.6856868,0.6856868,42539730`

Comment: Difficult to give you a general solution, just one that will work in that particular case. Does the string comes from a CSV file or something? You might have to fix the problem before getting here.

Comment: You'll probably need to split the string first... Problem is that this solution is only for this specific case, knowing where the commas are

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it sounds like you want to replace every odd-numbered comma starting from the third.

```
$parts = explode(",",$input_string);
$head = array_splice($parts,0,2);
$tail = array_chunk($parts,2);
$result = implode(",",$head) . "," . implode(",",
    array_map(function($p) {return implode(".",$p);}, $tail));
```

See it in action [here](http://ideone.com/p0rrXa).

---

For older versions of PHP, try:

```
$parts = explode(",",$input_string);
$head = array_splice($parts,0,2);
$tail = array_chunk($parts,2);
$result = implode(",",$head) . "," . implode(",",
    array_map(create_function('$p','return implode(".",$p);'), $tail));
```

Comment: these array functions really frustrates me.... never could figure out the sequence.... awesome job btw. +1

Comment: dear friend thank you. i have problem. Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION, expecting

Comment: @AhmetTepe Ah, you're stuck on an old version of PHP. Let me add a more compatible version.

Comment: @AhmetTepe If this answer solved your problem, please take a moment to mark it as Accepted by clicking the check mark under the score :)